# Update imported foreign table and update statement updates incorectly

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I have two table: table_1 and table_2.

```
create table table_1 
(
    user_id        integer,
    dt             date,
    s_wager     numeric,
    lst_update     timestamp,
    must_be_insert integer,
    constraint table_1 _pk_uniq
        unique (user_id, dt)
);

create table table_2
(
    user_id          integer,
    game_date        date,
    s_wager       numeric default 0,
    s_update_date timestamp,
    w_batch_id   bigint,
    constraint table_2_uniq
        unique (user_id, game_date)
)
    partition by RANGE (game_date);
```

`table_2` is foreign table imported from another server, what I am trying is to update data from `table_1` to `table_2`.

Here is update I wrote:

```
UPDATE table_2
SET s_wager       = b.slot_wager,
    s_update_date = b.lst_update,
    wager_batch_id = null
FROM (select aas.user_id, aas.dt, aas.s_wager, aas.lst_update
      from  table_1 aas
      ) b
WHERE table_2.user_id = b.user_id
  AND table_2.game_date = b.dt;
```

in `table_1` I have 2700 rows but in `table_2` more than 5000 row updates when the query is executed so why it happens? Any suggestions?

Comment: I have updated query @LaurenzAlbe

Comment: That cannot happen. Perhaps the (undisclosed) foreign table definition has a problem. How did you measure the number of updated rows?

Comment: update table_2 
set wager_batch_id =-1
where wager_batch_id is null;

I am running this and after this, I am running an update statement, and then


select count(*)
from table_2 
where wager_batch_id is null

and the count is more than 2700

Comment: 1) You don't need the sub-select you can just use table_1 directly in the `FROM`. 2) If you want to keep the sub-select you don't need the double alias, just use `table_1` inside the () and `b` as the alias. 3) What does `select count(*) from table_2` return? 4) I'm betting `table_2.user_id = b.user_id  AND table_2.game_date = b.dt` is selecting more then 2700 rows in `table_2`.

Comment: I dropped this imported table and recreated it without partition and the update worked, but after I recreated it with partition it had errors, I think partitioning is not reached, or something happened

Comment: Well, we will never know, since you didn't provide enough information.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax and logic of the SQL UPDATE statement you provide seem to be correct. However, the data in your tables and the uniqueness criteria you've established can be the reason why more rows in table_2 are being changed than you expect.
Check the data in table_1 and table_2 to see if there are any similarities or differences.

You can examine which rows were updated and what values were set by including a RETURNING clause in your UPDATE statement.  This might assist you in identifying the exact rows that are receiving more updates than expected. try this code;

```
UPDATE table_2
SET s_wager = b.slot_wager,
    s_update_date = b.lst_update,
    wager_batch_id = null
FROM (select aas.user_id, aas.dt, aas.s_wager, aas.lst_update
      from table_1 aas
      ) b
WHERE table_2.user_id = b.user_id
  AND table_2.game_date = b.dt
RETURNING *;
```

Hope it works :)

Comment: RETURNING *;
 is a good idea but I checked every row that updated incorrectly, after dropping the imported table and recreating it without partition the update I provided worked